# search number from lines and place in specific sentence

Tags: python, linux, awk

I am struggling with some python code.

I have a file with many lines e.g

```
50
22
35
41
```

I wish to add these into a sentences of similar structure however keeping the order of the lines.

E.g

```
This is test 50 of this friday
This is test 22 of this friday
This is test 35 of this friday
This is test 41 of this friday
```

Comment: post your so far code

Comment: `awk '{print "This is test ",$1, " of this friday"}' file`?

Comment: Is this homework? What does your code look like?

Comment: There's just no way you could be struggling with something apparently this trivial in ANY tool. What is it you're not telling us?

Answer (score 1):

You tagged the question with `python` and `awk`. For something this trivial `awk` seems the clear choice:

```
$ awk '{printf "This is a test %d of this friday\n",$0}' file
This is a test 50 of this friday
This is a test 22 of this friday
This is a test 35 of this friday
This is a test 41 of this friday
```

Answer (score 1):

Fairly easy in Python:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print("This is a test {} of this friday".format(line.strip()))
```

Comment: you are going to have to strip the newline from `line` before passing it to `format`

Answer (score 0):

sed one-liner

```
sed 's/.*/This is test & of this friday/' file
```

or python (2.7)

```
with open('file') as f:
    for x in f:
        print "this is test %s of this friday" % x.strip()
```